# In Uno, can you play a Reverse card on a Draw 4 card and make that player draw 4 cards instead?

Tags: uno

We just want to know if you can play a Reverse card on a Draw 2 or 4 card and have that player draw cards instead?

[image]

Comment: OP do you play with the stacking draw 2/4 house rule (allows playing a draw 2 on a previously played draw 2, adding two cards to the number of cards drawn by player who doesn't have a draw 2 to add to the stack)? Seems like a reasonable house rule to add playing reverses on the stack. Remember, everyone playing has to agree to house rules before play begins.

Answer (score 11):

You can't

According to the uno rules a draw 2 means:

> Draw Two – When a person places this card, the next player will have to pick up two cards and forfeit his/her turn.

Meaning you don't have a chance to play the reverse card and let the other person draw the cards